# ImportError cannot import name when using baseclass with multiple subclasses

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I need to have a base class that runs setup/teardown, then subclasses that inherit, in order to allow for all tests to run regardless if certain ones fail. When attempting to have multiple subclasses that import a base class, I see an import error for the second subclass.  I have the following files:
`runtestcases.py`
`testcase1.py`
`testcase2.py`

Here is runtestcases.py:

```
import unittest
import testcase1, testcase2

class ArithTestSuper (unittest.TestCase):

def setUp (self):
    print("Setting up ArithTest cases")

def tearDown (self):
    print("Cleaning up ArithTest cases")


def my_suite():

suite = unittest.TestSuite()

suite.addTest (testcase1.ArithTest())
suite.addTest (testcase2.ArithTestFail())

return suite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    test_suite = my_suite()
    runner.run (test_suite)
```

Here is testcase1.py:

```
from runtestcases import ArithTestSuper

class ArithTest (ArithTestSuper):

def runTest (self):
    """ Test addition and succeed. """
    print("Running ArithTest")
    self.failUnless (1+1==2, 'one plus one fails!')
    self.failIf (1+1 != 2, 'one plus one fails again!')
    self.failUnlessEqual (1+1, 2, 'more trouble with one plus one!')
```

Here is testcase2.py:

```
from runtestcases import ArithTestSuper

class ArithTestFail (ArithTestSuper):

def runTest (self):
    """ Test addition and fail. """
    print("Running ArithTestFail")
    self.failUnless (1+1==2, 'one plus one fails!')
    self.failIf (1+1 != 2, 'one plus one fails again!')
    self.failUnlessEqual (1+1, 2, 'more trouble with one plus one!')
    self.failIfEqual (1+1, 2, 'expected failure here')
    self.failIfEqual (1+1, 2, 'second failure')  


Compilation fails on testcase2.py with:
ImportError: cannot import name ArithTestSuper
```

If I run just testcase1 it works - likewise, running just testcase2 works.  If I try both this error occurs.  Thoughts?

Comment: remove the line `from runtestcases import ArithTestSuper` from testcase1 and testcase2 and run runtestcases.py again

Comment: I've tried that.  It ends up throwing: NameError: name 'ArithTestSuper' is not defined

Comment: @IonutHulub: wtf? that's clearly bogus advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with circular imports. Move your base class out of the module you run.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question ([https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885312/1745627](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885312/1745627%20/)): avoid overriding the `runTest` method; it is to be called by the unittest framework, and essentially does the job of runing your testcase. Implement your own test methods using a naming convention like `test_xxx` (unittest looks for methods starting with `test` to execute).

Comment: @tera_incognita I think you overlooked this one... you are overriding the wrong method ('runTest').